# Adress/Queue Creation & Journal Sync in Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to do few samples on artemis and any help with below questions is great for better design of the system.

1. If we choose to create queues through CLI/web console option , does the queue info stored inside bindings journal as I don't see broker xml getting updated ? If so broker instance on boot loads all addresses present in broker.xml along with the addresses created through CLI ? please correct the understanding if any. I am looking to have automated way of creating queues and looking for best option without restarting server.
2. Our topology is going to be network replicated mode of master-slave pair. So is it enough to create queues in master and they gets synced to slave? In other words , journal synchronization refers to bindings as well as message journals and all below directories gets synced to slave over network replication ?
   **Directories I can see** : Paging , Bindings , Journal , Large messages

Reference :
https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addresses and queue created via management (e.g. web console, CLI, etc.) are stored in the bindings journal and reloaded when the broker starts. Any resources which are persisted to the journal are replicated to the backup.

In short, the answers to your questions are yes and yes.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the quick response.  I feel better to go with broker.XML or separate XML config only as any ways even if we create via other ways , we need broker xml for adding more like address or security settings. So defining in XML and maintaining in repository seems a good option.    Also , I edited the question with 1 more point , if you could help with some pointers , would be helpful. Thanks a lot..

Comment: You should create a new question otherwise your question likely get closed. Each question should only focus on a single issue.